# Form not showing up in my Emulator

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have a mac pro. I installed xamarin studio and everything I needed for android development on mac. The first time I created a project I ran it and everything works. I was able to click on a button which counted my number of clicks kind of like a default.

I decided to follow the Android quick start tutorial on Xamarin and when I got done creating the project and ran it nothing showed in my emulator. The controls I created did not show up. All I got on top of the screen was "Deployment Completed" . No error messages either. How do I trouble shoot this? I want to be able to see the screen I created in the Emulator and click on various buttons.

[image]

Now I just got an error message and it can be found below.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Warning: No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2047-01-01) or after any future revocation date. (Phoneword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your Android project did not actually get built either because you have selected the wrong configuration and platform pair or because the settings for the configuration and platform pair are not correct.

When building and running on Android, you want to make sure you change your **Platform** to `AnyCPU` and then either choose `Debug` or `Release` for your **Configuration** depending on what environment you are targeting. For building and running on iOS, you would just change the **Platform** to `iPhone Simulator` or `iPhone`.

See image below for how to access these settings (just click where the red boxes are circled):
[image: Xamarin Studio Platform and Configuration Screenshot]

In Xamarin Studio, with your project open:

1. Click **Project** -> **Solution Options**
2. Choose the **Configurations** tab
3. Choose the **Configuration Mappings** tab
4. Now change the **Configuration** dropdown to `Debug` and the **Platform** to `AnyCPU`
5. Make sure that the **Build** checkbox is checked next to your shared project (most likely the one at the top) and that the **Build** checkbox is checked next to your Android project
6. Now click OK, make sure you have the correct **Configuration** and **Platform** are selected
7. Rebuild the solution and try to run it again

*Edit: After talk in the comments, the emulator must be unlocked to actually view the running app. To unlock the emulator:

1. Click and hold down on the lock icon at the bottom of your emulator screen
2. Drag the mouse up to the top of the screen and release the click

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I have the exact setting you listed above and still nothing is displayed in the Emulator. I can hit the break points but nothing happens after that. Any idea of what I can check again ?

Comment: @user2320476 The warning you posted is not the issue, that shows because you are just debugging the app. Does the name of the emulator appear next to the Run button before you click it?

Comment: Yes the name appears

Comment: @user2320476 When you unlock the emulator, does the app show up in the app list?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that but can quickly try it now. This is my first time of using this product.

Comment: @user2320476 With the emulator open like you have it in the screenshot, just take your mouse, click and hold down on the lock icon, and drag the mouse up to unlock the emulator

Comment: Thanks. When I did that I was able to see my screen and the button I created. I clicked on it and it worked.

Comment: So that worked for the test application. Now when I try to do the same thing for my phoneword test application, all i get is "unfortunately, Phoneword has stopped"  click ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133366/discussion-between-hvaughan3-and-user2320476).

Comment: This is the exact problem I had. This video also helped in solving my problem. The issue has been resolved. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSu9z8G_MiU